# How to customize Action bar without change api level?

Tags: android, xml, fonts

How can i add custom font(Kulturista _Bold.ttf) to Action bar and change text color to #ffffff without changing min api level 11

Answer (score 0):

see [this](http://www.tristanwaddington.com/2013/03/styling-the-android-action-bar-with-a-custom-font/) it might be useful to you

Answer (score 0):

Use the support library you should have backward compatibility. Import the support library into your workspace which can be found in `~/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130729/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompact` and use is in your project. And also don't forget to add the support library which can be brought up right clicking into your project and entering `Android Tools -> Add Support Library`

Using `appcompact` you will have to extend your activity class with `ActionBarActivity`. And also using the `appcompact` you have to make changes in your styles folder. You could refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Adding). Do not also forget to update the `values-v11` and `values-v14` file. Doing all of this will make your application compatible.

P.S. If any error occurs in your `appcompact` library. Don't panic look at the error logs and open the file that seems to contain the error. Most probably you will have to refresh the file and after that you just `fix project properties`, and the error goes away.

For custom font, add to assests:

[image]

Create a helper class to initialize font:

```
public class Utils {

     public static Typeface fontsStyle;

        public static void TypeFaceOne(TextView tv, AssetManager asm){

            fontsStyle=Typeface.createFromAsset(asm, "fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"); 
            tv.setTypeface(fontsStyle);
        }
}
```

Finally use a custom view for actionbar:

```
this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
this.getSupprotActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.customabview, null);

//customize text
Utils.TypeFaceOne(textview, getAssets());
textview.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
this.getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(v);
```

Hope this helps :)